# Any chance to connect to CouchbaseMock with 2.0+ java api?

Tags: couchbase

A lot of people were asking this question some time ago and I would be happy to know if there is a chance to support that? I really do not want to resign from nice rx.java api to be able to run my integration tests locally.

1. Anyone succeed connecting to CouchbaseMock with java api 2.0?
2. For Couchbase related people: Any plans to support this in the future?
3. Is there any other implementation of Couchbase mock, maybe in different language?

Attaching the log from my last attempt, looks like the api is throwing NPE.

```
> Mar 14, 2017 10:04:39 AM com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore
> <init> INFO: CouchbaseEnvironment: {sslEnabled=false,
> sslKeystoreFile='null', sslKeystorePassword=false, sslKeystore=null,
> bootstrapHttpEnabled=true, bootstrapCarrierEnabled=true,
> bootstrapHttpDirectPort=7777, bootstrapHttpSslPort=18091,
> bootstrapCarrierDirectPort=55001, bootstrapCarrierSslPort=11207,
> ioPoolSize=8, computationPoolSize=8, responseBufferSize=16384,
> requestBufferSize=16384, kvServiceEndpoints=1,
> viewServiceEndpoints=12, queryServiceEndpoints=12,
> searchServiceEndpoints=12, ioPool=NioEventLoopGroup, kvIoPool=null,
> viewIoPool=null, searchIoPool=null, queryIoPool=null,
> coreScheduler=CoreScheduler,
> memcachedHashingStrategy=DefaultMemcachedHashingStrategy,
> eventBus=DefaultEventBus,
> packageNameAndVersion=couchbase-java-client/2.4.2 (git: 2.4.2, core:
> 1.4.2), dcpEnabled=false, retryStrategy=BestEffort, maxRequestLifetime=75000, retryDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0
> MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=100, upper=100000},
> reconnectDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MILLISECONDS, powers of 2;
> lower=32, upper=4096}, observeIntervalDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy
> 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=10, upper=100000}, keepAliveInterval=30000, autoreleaseAfter=2000,
> bufferPoolingEnabled=true, tcpNodelayEnabled=true,
> mutationTokensEnabled=false, socketConnectTimeout=1000,
> dcpConnectionBufferSize=20971520, dcpConnectionBufferAckThreshold=0.2,
> dcpConnectionName=dcp/core-io, callbacksOnIoPool=false,
> disconnectTimeout=25000,
> requestBufferWaitStrategy=com.couchbase.client.core.env.DefaultCoreEnvironment$2@7d3a22a9,
> queryTimeout=75000, viewTimeout=75000, kvTimeout=2500,
> connectTimeout=5000, dnsSrvEnabled=false} Mar 14, 2017 10:04:40 AM
> com.couchbase.client.core.node.CouchbaseNode signalConnected INFO:
> Connected to Node 127.0.0.1 Mar 14, 2017 10:04:40 AM
> com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler
> exceptionCaught WARNING: [/127.0.0.1:55001][KeyValueEndpoint]: Caught
> unknown exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:266)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
>   ... 31 more
> 
> Mar 14, 2017 10:04:40 AM
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
> onUnhandledInboundException WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was
> fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means
> the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:266)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
>   ... 31 more
> 
> Mar 14, 2017 10:04:40 AM
> com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler
> exceptionCaught WARNING: [/127.0.0.1:55001][KeyValueEndpoint]: Caught
> unknown exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:266)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
>   ... 31 more
> 
> Mar 14, 2017 10:04:40 AM
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
> onUnhandledInboundException WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was
> fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means
> the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:266)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
>   ... 31 more
> 
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
> com.couchbase.client.core.utils.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:74)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:310)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:288)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:278)
>   at
> com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:262)
>   at com.mycompany.ohsm.io.Test.main(Test.java:27) Caused by:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     ... 6 more
```

Mock Server (1.4.4):

```
final CouchbaseMock couchbaseMock =
                new CouchbaseMock("localhost", 7777, 1, 0, 1024, "couchbase::memcache", 0);
        couchbaseMock.start();
        couchbaseMock.waitForStartup();
```

Client (2.4.2):

```
final DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().
                bootstrapCarrierEnabled(true).
                bootstrapHttpEnabled(true).
                bootstrapHttpDirectPort(7777).
                sslEnabled(false).
                bootstrapCarrierDirectPort(55001).
                build();

        CouchbaseCluster couchbaseCluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "127.0.0.1");


        final Bucket couchbase = couchbaseCluster.openBucket("couchbase");
        final JsonDocument doc = couchbase.get("key");
```

Comment: Is there any reason a single-node Couchbase instance on localhost can't work for you?  What are the problems in doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your java client CouchbaseEnvironment has memcached port as 55001, not sure how you had set it on the mock. I just tried basic operations with 2.x java client and mock, they worked fine.

Comment: Added the test and sample configuration here. http://review.couchbase.org/#/c/75188/ If you are using master of CouchbaseMock, a slight change is required.

Comment: Thanks subhashni. I pulled the port directly from couchbaseMock debugging it. When I run your example I am getting 404 trying to getPortInfo. I will try to investigate that further..

Comment: It got the reponse with port when I changed the path to /mock/get_mcports but still I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:73)

Comment: I got your test running when I pulled the project from git so I guess it works. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not aware of any reason this shouldn't work, but I'll ask some colleagues to jump in on this.
2. At the moment, CouchbaseMock is a maintained project and useful for a lot of these cases, but we don't have an intent for it to be a complete mock in the near term.  Rather, we'd like to remove the barriers to using a cluster-of-one or like.
3. Nothing as complete.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the answer. I attached the debug information.